# Services not starting after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, do-release-upgrade

After upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 and rebooting, my laptop gets stuck in the loading screen. Hitting escape while the loading indicator is spinning shows output from the boot process. In this output, it looks like my system is now in a loop where it attempts to start 3 services over and over again. The messaged I'm getting:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
See 'systemctl status systemd-oomd.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
```

Once these failures occur, the system just retries, over and over again, and the system fails to boot.

How do I fix this? Never had this issue in 20.04.

Comment: You can boot from live. USB, then mount your drives, then `chroot` to your actual "/" (ie root disk)--find a guide, you probably want to `source` too--, then do eg `systemctl status systemd-oomd.service` (as in your error messages). It might be sufficient to run an apt full-upgrade, maybe some package installs failed? Post any output that looks useful (eg use pastebin), particularly from `journalctl -b` (logs of your last boot). Hope that overview is enough to get you going, you seem competent so I kept it high level.

Comment: None of those is vital for ordinary boot, you may be able to disable those services. You'll need to hand write a resolv.conf file (eg "nameserver 8.8.8.8") to get online in that case.